# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence - minimal working, maven based, example needed

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I am trying to start a new web project with EclipseLink + JPA. Everything works fine until the execution is started - once the connection to the database should be established, an exception is raised:

"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence".

I think I generally know what this error means (java is not able to find the class); however, I am not able to get over it. I have tried many examples from StackOverflow showing which dependencies should be imported, but none of them worked for me.

I have created a minimal not-working example.

Simple JSP page with:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <body>
  <%
    Class.forName("javax.persistence.Persistence");
  %>
  </body>
</html>
```

and maven with dependencies

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derbyclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.15.2.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.5.1</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.0.0</version>-->
<!--            <scope>compile</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        &lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api -->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.5.1</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.1.0</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        
    </dependencies>
```

- I have tried all of them including the commented.
  Environment: IntelliJ Idea, Java 13.

May there be an issue in something else, or am I overlooking something?

If somebody can send me `pom.xml` file, which is working, it will be very appreciated.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally got it, and maybe helpful for somebody.

The main issue is that the library, although correctly imported by Maven, was not exported in the artifact. Therefore, the executed web application was not able to find the class.

The downloaded .jar file must be added into the "lib" folder in the output artifact.

May be helpful for somebody.